# Porting following structure to Laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel

I am having the following structure in a prototype sample application

```
buildings/

building_one.class.php
building_two.class.php
```

One of the classes above are dynamically included from a request looking like this:

```
build.php?id=1
```

It would take the id (positioning) and then include and create the building_one request, and then dependant on what method is actually called a method the class has will be.

etc. If there is no POST request being made a display() method would be called displaying a unique form for the building, if the building form is submitted an upgrade() method would be called, etc.

I'm not sure how I would create the buildings/ structure in a Laravel application. How do  I? Are the represented as models? Controllers?

Answer (score -1):

So buildings/ us the URL or is it also a class?